# importar *.txt como parametro de una funcion

Tags: python-3.x

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
def propietario(nombre, carnet):
    print('el propietario es: {}, cuyo carnet de identidad es: {}'.format(nombre, carnet)
```

pero el valor del nombre y del carnet de identidad estan en un *.txt externo.

como puedo hacer para leer el fichero y decirle a la funcion que tome los parametros de la misma?

```
from io import open

listaNombres = open('datos_externos.txt','r')

leyendo = listaNombres.readlines()

listaNombres.close()
```

y el archivo txt: datos_externos.txt tiene la informacion de esta forma:

'mario',810223

'penelope',236235

etc

Comment: ¿A la función que le pasarías el usuario o el carnet para que lo busque en el fichero? Obviamente, si le pasas los dos no tiene sentido buscar nada.

Comment: de eso se trata, como puedo pasarle los valores que tengo en el texto a propetario...normalmente si escribimos propietario(juan,125632) funcionaria, pero yo lo que quiero es que propietario pueda tomar lso parametros de este txt externo

Comment: Si si eso lo entiendo, pero el txt se supone que tiene varios propietarios almacenados y la función debe encargarse de buscar uno entre ellos a no ser que entendiera mal. Ahora bien, para que encuentre el que se quiere y pueda obtener sus datos  necesitará al menos uno de los dos datos, o el dni o el nombre.

Comment: si, se podria iterar despues, no hay problema. Para mi duda en particular podemos hacer lo siguiente: el txt solo tiene un valor de propietario:'Juan',521229...y lo que deseo es poder decirle a propietario que tome los dos parametros de este txt...normalmente cuando uno le escribe lso parametros funciona, pero para que lso tome del txt es que tengo el problema que no se hacerlo

Comment: Si tu problema es parsear el archivo es otra cosa, por ejemplo, si no tienes nunca comas en el nombre, puedes hacer simplemente:  `nombre, dni = linea.split(",")`. Por ejemplo, en tu caso para obtener el primer nombre y su dni puedes hacer `nombre, dni = leyendo[0].split(",")`. Lo suyo sería usar el módulo csv dado que lo que tienes es en principio un csv. No se si es a esto a lo que te refieres.

Comment: exacto. Es que no se como hacer que el string obtenido del *.txt pudiera ser asimilado com oparametro en la funcion propietario. por ejemplo, cuando doy:  `print(leyendo)` el resultado es ["'Juan',810220\n"] y eso no se como poderlo pasar como parametro de la funcion. por ejemplo, de una lista L = [1,2,3] lo normal seria que L[0] fuera igual a 1, etc pero eso no se cumple en el caso anterior.